# Updating Yeoman gives cb never called

Tags: node.js, npm, homebrew, yeoman

I'm using `npm update -g -yo` to update yeoman to the latest version. But I always get this error: `npm ERR! cb() never called!`.

Mind you, I had node installed initially, then I did `npm cache clean -f` then reinstalled it with Homebrew, `brew install -g node`. And I'm still getting the same error mentioned above.

All of this is in terminal on a mac.

Can someone advice me, please?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please don't use `npm update -g` for now; it's still broken.

I would recommend uninstalling and reinstalling node, then updating `npm` and installing `yo`:

`brew uninstall node
brew install -g node
npm install -g npm@latest
npm install -g yo@latest`

In general when you want to update a global package, use `npm install -g <package>@latest`